# notificaciones bloquedas desde las opciones del telefono

Tags: flutter

mi problema es el siguiente:
cuando inicializa la aplicacion me pide permiso para enviar notificaciones
pero cuando le doy en permitir me lleva hasta las opciones de permisos de la aplicacion.
y la opcion de notificaciones esta totalmente bloqueda, no me deja hacer ninguna accion de activar o desactivar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy utilizando el paquete de awesome notifications pero no funciona

```
  void main() async {
  //making sure the process can pass
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
//initialing notifications
  print('INITIALIZING NOTIS ');
  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://drawable/defaulticon',
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'scheduled_channel',
        channelName: 'Weather Notifications',
        defaultColor: Colors.amber,
        importance: NotificationImportance.High,
        channelShowBadge: true,
      )
    ],
  );

  

  runApp(const AppState());
}
```

lo extraño es que cuando lo intente con el paquete de flutter_notifications
si me funcionaba, ven algo en la inicializacion que me este bloqueando las notificaciones desde las opciones del telefono